# BIDS 2012 SQL Log provider: The connection xxx is not found

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis, bids

I'm facing a weird situation while configuring logging for packages. I created a new project from scratch, configured SQL Server login provider with a package OLE DB connection and everything runs fine.

If I promote the aforementioned connection to become a project connection, then I get this error all the time:

"Error: 0xC001000E at Package: The connection "xxxx" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found."

If I change back the connection to become a package connection, everything goes back to normal.

What I'm doing wrong? I'm running Visual Studio Data Tools 2012 version 11.0.61030.0 on W7 X64. SQL Server is 2014. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Project connection manager is different from a Package level connection manager. After converting to a Project level CM, go into the Logging screen and click the dropdown for the connection manager.

As you can see below, even though I have a SportsData connection manager defined, it's not an option here because it's a project level connection manager.

[image]

If I convert it back to package level, then it shows up in the drop down. If I were to reverse the order of operations: add my CM as a package level to the logging and *then* convert to project, I will still see it in the drop down but as you've discovered, that doesn't work.

I found [this note](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2011/07/19/project-connection-managers.aspx) and a promise it'd be fixed before RTM.

> Logging might not always work. There might be scenarios where if you log on a project connection manager the logging won’t appear in the package logging

As my wife says, wish one in hand, sh*t in the other and see which one fills up first.

All of that said, do you have a specific reason for logging? Do you know that by virtue of using the Project Deployment Model, executions from the server are automatically logged to the SSISDB database. No explicit logging set up required. I've been able to answer all the questions I normally want to know about an SSIS execution by querying `SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages`